# Sending messages between processes in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to implement communication between processes using signals. First the parent starts the child process, it does some work and then waits for a message from the child, then signals the child again, so the child can continue its processing and so on.

I am not sure what is the correct approach to implement this, but here is my first try:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $forever=1000000;
my $parPID=$$;
my $child = fork();
if( $child == 0 ){
  runSubProc($parPID,$forever);
}

$SIG{"USR1"}=sub { 
  say "Parent: got signal 1";
  $SIG{"USR1"}=sub {
    say "Parent: got signal 2";
    exit 0;
  };
  sleep 5;
  kill 'USR1', $child;
  sleep $forever;
};

say "Waiting for child processes..";
sleep $forever;


sub runSubProc {
  my ($parPID,$forever)=@_;

  $SIG{"USR1"}=sub { 
    say "Child: got signal 1"; 
    $SIG{"USR1"}=sub {
      say "Child: got signal 2"; 
      exit 0;
    };
    sleep 7;
    kill 'USR1', $parPID;
    sleep $forever;
  };
  sleep 5;
  kill 'USR1', $parPID;
  sleep $forever;
}
```

This does not work, the output is:

```
Waiting for child processes..
Parent: got signal 1
Child: got signal 1
```

and then it hangs..

Comment: try running with `strace -fTt ./scriptname`. I would guess that your signals are being fired more than once - bear in mind that the 'signal handler' is a bailout, rather than being re-entrant.
I think the core of your problem will be - you're redefining your 'signal handler' from within the signal handler. But I'll have a fiddle and see if I can make it go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root cause is your `sleep $forever` within the signal handler. Because your process is *already* handling a 'SIGUSR1' the next kill signal doesn't get processed - this is to avoid all sorts of nastiness with signals interrupting signals. Avoid anything that'll block within your handler.

This seems to work:

```
$SIG{'USR1'} = \&handle_USR1;

my $ppid      = $$;
my $child_pid = fork();

sub handle_USR1 {
    if ( $signalled++ ) { print "$$: got second USR1\n"; exit 0 }

    print "$$: caught SIGUSR1\n";
    if ( not $child_pid ) {
        print "$$: Child got a SIGUSR1\n";
        sleep 7;
        print "$$: (child) sending signal to $ppid\n";
        kill 'USR1', $ppid;
    } else {
        print "$$: (parent) got USR1\n";
        sleep 5;
        print "$$: parent signalling child\n";
        kill 'USR1', $child_pid;
    }
}

if ($child_pid) {
    print "$$ ( parent ) waiting\n";
    sleep 500;
} else {
    print "$$: (child) waiting\n";
    sleep 5;
    print "$$: Child signalling $ppid\n";
    kill 'USR1', $ppid;
    sleep 500;
}
```

You might need to reshuffle a little but the core point is - redefining your signal handlers on the fly, and most especially 'stalling' them by putting the sleep in there is going to break the signalling mechanism.

Comment: You've made some very nice contributions this week.  Kudos

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation! It seems like the `sleep 500` is not continuing after the signal. After the signal handler has run the program will then exit.

Comment: Not on my Unix box any more, so can't verify (Windows doesn't let me use SIGUSR1). But that will probably be because the `kill` interrupts the `sleep`, and then the process exits normally (because sleep is the last line). So you might need to sit in a loop instead. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html - it won't 'go back into' the sleep subroutine.